# Can we have different colors for different markers in folium map? Different colors for different range of frequency signal

Tags: python, pandas, google-maps, data-science, folium

[Sample_csv_data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lO0mu.png)

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('C:/Nishant/Gtech/folium.csv',sep=',')
subset=df.sample(n=700)
subset.tail()
```

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fegdl.jpg)

```py
import folium from folium.plugins 
import FastMarkerCluster

print(df['Lon'].mean())
print(df['Lat'].mean())

m=folium.Map(location=[df['Lat'].mean(),df['Lon'].mean()],zoom_start=25)

def add_marker(row):
    marker = folium.CircleMarker([row['Lat'],row['Lon']],radius=2,color='red',popup=row['RSRP_Signal'])

marker.add_to(m) 

subset.apply(add_marker,axis=1)

m.save('C:/Nishant/Gtech/folium.html')

m
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Unfortunately, this question is not detailed enough to give you any meaningful help. Please edit your question to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for the issue, including sample input, preferred output, and code for what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

```
import folium
from folium.plugins 
import FastMarkerCluster


print(df['Lon'].mean() )

print(df['Lat'].mean())


m=folium.Map(location=[df['Lat'].mean(),df['Lon'].mean()],zoom_start=15)
def add_marker(row):
    if row['RSRP_Signal']>-80:

marker=folium.CircleMarker([row['Lat'],row['Lon']],radius=2,color='green',popup=row['RSRP_Signal'])
        marker.add_to(m)

    elif row['RSRP_Signal']>-100:
        marker=folium.CircleMarker([row['Lat'],row['Lon']],radius=2,color='blue',popup=row['RSRP_Signal'])
        marker.add_to(m)

    else:
        marker=folium.CircleMarker([row['Lat'],row['Lon']],radius=2,color='red',popup=row['RSRP_Signal'])
        marker.add_to(m)


subset.apply(add_marker,axis=1)
m.save('C:/Nishant/Gtech/folium.html')
m
```

Comment: Are you able to explain how you use folium.plugins.FastMarkerCluster?